# How to show "@coroutine#2","@coroutine#3","@coroutine#1" in kotlin coroutine?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-coroutines

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun log(msg: String) = println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val a = async {
        log("I'm computing a piece of the answer")
        6
    }
    val b = async {
        log("I'm computing another piece of the answer")
        7
    }
    log("The answer is ${a.await() * b.await()}")    
}
```

Document of kotlin

> [main @coroutine#2] I'm computing a piece of the answer [main
> @coroutine#3] I'm computing another piece of the answer [main
> @coroutine#1] The answer is 42

My IDE of Intellij IDEA and Android

> [main] I'm computing a piece of the answer [main] I'm computing
> another piece of the answer [main] The answer is 42

How to show "@coroutine#2","@coroutine#3","@coroutine#1"????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **Run/Debug Configurations** window and add `-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug` to the **VM options**:

[image]

After doing that you'll get this output:

```
[main @coroutine#2] I'm computing a piece of the answer
[main @coroutine#3] I'm computing another piece of the answer
[main @coroutine#1] : The answer is 42
```